# Further parallelize calculation of two Java parallelStream()

Tags: java, concurrency, java-8, java-stream

I have a method that computes the squares of the numbers in a list in parallel and sums them up:

```
public static double sumSquared(List<Double> values) {
    return values
            .parallelStream()
            .mapToDouble(d -> d * d)
            .sum();
}
```

How can this be further parallelized assuming there are a few lists of double, e.g.

```
double result = sumSquared(list0) + (sumSquared(list1) * sumSquared(list2));
```

Is there an elegant way? I suppose starting separate threads for each of the list operations doesn't help much as they utilize the same thread pool. Does it make sense at all or should the result be calculated as stated above?

Comment: What do you mean by 'as they utilize the same thread pool'. I think using a dedicated threadpool would be a good way to achieve further parallelisation !

Comment: I mean, that the usage of parallelStream() acquires processing resources from the same threadpool no matter what list is processed and that pool is sized according to the underlying hardware. (This is how I think it works)

Comment: I assume you're posting a simplified example. The parallelism of real world cases may be more limited. And in that case parallelizing further *might* make sense.

Comment: I was looking for a way to achieve what Didier proposed in his answer using the CompletionStage class. It was just what I was missing because the stream processing to me feels more like performing operations linearly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is indeed that even if `sumSquared()` processes data in parallel, each of the `sumSquared()` calls is performed sequentially. The lists are thus still processed one by one, hence losing CPU processing time if some of those lists are too small to be split across several CPU's.

To avoid this, run the whole computation in parallel using the new [`CompletionStage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html)/[`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) introduced in Java 8:

```
// each sumSquared() is submitted immediately to the common pool
CompletionStage<Double> sumList0 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> sumSquared(list0));
CompletionStage<Double> sumList1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> sumSquared(list1));
CompletionStage<Double> sumList2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> sumSquared(list2));

// as soon as sumList1 and sumList2 have both complete, their product is computed
CompletionStage<Double> prodSumList1and2 = sumList1.thenCombine(sumList2, (a, b) -> a * b);
// as soon as their product is computed and sumList0 is finished, the final sum is computed
CompletionStage<Double> result = sumList0.thenCombine(prodSumList1and2, Double::sum);

System.out.println(result.toCompletableFuture().get());
```

Note that this uses the common pool, which is sized by default to use all your CPU's. Using a custom pool will thus probably not improve performance if you are only performing CPU-heavy operations, except if you have other jobs running in parallel.

Things might be different though if your processing is more I/O bound or memory bound for example.